# CSV file seen as 'data' rather than 'ASCII' by OS after written via Python

Tags: python, file, unix, csv, ascii

I'm using Python 2.7.5 to read in a CSV file (input.csv), ignore certain lines, and write the result to a new CSV file (output.csv).  I've made many different attempts, but they all result in the output file being seen by the operating system (both Red Hat and Mac OS X) as 'data', rather than 'ASCII text'.

#### input.csv:

```
cat -v input.csv (truncated)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Spooler,yes,1^M
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs,no,A^M
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager,seed,0x714b3c99^M

file input.csv
input.csv: data
```

#### script.py (latest attempt):

```
import io

input_file = '/Users/spork_user/Desktop/input.csv'
output_file = '/Users/spork_user/Desktop/output.csv'    

with io.open(input_file, 'r', newline='\r\n') as infile, io.open(output_file, 'w', newline='\n') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        #filters for lines I don't want, for example:
        if "Does not exist" in line:
            continue

        #to verify how the line appears to python when it reads it in
        print repr(line)

        #without the rstrip, i get a blank line between each line in my output, and it's still seen as 'data'
        outfile.write(unicode(line.rstrip('\r\n')+'\n'))
```

#### Run:

```
python script.py (truncated)
u'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Windows\\Spooler,yes,1\r\n'
u'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Windows\\AppInit_DLLs,no,A\r\n'
u'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager,seed,0x714b3c99\r\n'
```

#### output.csv:

```
cat -v output.csv (truncated)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Spooler,yes,1
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs,no,A
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager,seed,0x714b3c99

file output.csv
output.csv: data
```

No matter what combination of open read/write flags or stripping of newline characters I try, the output.csv file always ends up being seen by the OS as 'data'.

---

**However**, if I make a simplified script with hardcoded output, it provides me with the ASCII type of file I'm looking for:

#### simplified.py:

```
import io

output_file = '/Users/spork_user/Desktop/simple_output.csv'
with io.open(output_file, 'w', newline='\n') as outfile:
    outfile.write(unicode('hello\n'))
    outfile.write(unicode('this\n'))
    outfile.write(unicode('works\n'))
```

#### Run:

```
python simplified.py
<no output>
```

#### simple_output.csv:

```
cat -v simple_output.csv
hello
this
works

file simple_output.csv
simple_output.csv: ASCII text
```

How can I get output.csv to be seen by the OS as ASCII text like simple_output.csv?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `input.csv` file is correct. In order to ease porting of CSV files across different architecture the convention is that the end of line should be a `\r\n` even if local convention for text file in '\n' (Unix-like) or `\r` (Mac)

The problem is that the file utility is not aware of that and **erroneously** points the file as binary, where it could say *text/csv file* or at least *MS/DOS text file*

Reference: [Comma-Separated Values on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) says :

*Standardization*

...

*RFC 4180 formalized CSV. It defines the MIME type "text/csv", and CSV files that follow its rules should be very widely portable. Among its requirements:*

- *MS-DOS-style lines that end with (CR/LF) characters (optional for the last line)*
- ...

What to do then : just ignore the problem of `file` saying the file is data, it is a perfectly correct text/csv file (and anyway, good editors like [vim](http://www.vim.org) can cope with different conventions for end of line)